# underscore templates in marionettejs Attribute not defined

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette, backbone-views

I have got a problem with an underscore template.

I fetch my current user on the startup of the application. So i create an instance by passing the id, which i take from a cookie. I pass this model to the view and fetch it there (it doesnt matter where i do this it is asynchronous).

I have some i18n by the require.js plugin (var msg), so i use the function `serializeData`:

```
if (this.model.attributes.name) {
    msg.model = this.model.toJSON();
}

return msg;
```

In my underscore template i want to display the username if possible, so i do

```
<% var model = model; if (model) { %>
    <%= model.name.givenName %>
<% } %>
```

I figured out that if i dont call `var model = model` i cannot even check for its existence by `if (model)` because it will throw an `undefined error`.

I feel a little bit bad about this because i don't know how to do better. Maybe i should use handlebars or mustache instead of the microtemplating. How do i solve this ugly problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check like this

```
if (typeof model != "undefined" && model.name != undefined && model.name.givenName != undefined ) {
    ...
}
```

it has something to do with Javascript's weird grammar.

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with "weird grammar", it has to do with Underscore's templates using [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to simulate a bunch of local variables using an object. Have a look at the `source` property of a compiled template function and you'll see the `with`.